# Unable to publish builds from Azure pipelines to Appcenter

Tags: azure-devops

Error received - ##[error]"{"message":"Unauthorized. Correlation ID: xxxxx","statusCode":401,"code":"Unauthorized"}"

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.apk'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/app/build/outputs/'
    artifactName: 'apk-files-$(apk_suffix)'
    artifactType: 'container'

- task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  inputs:
    serverEndpoint: 'CICD'
    appSlug: 'OrgCICD/appname'
    appFile: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/app/build/outputs/apk/appname/release/appname-release.apk '
    symbolsOption: 'Android'
    releaseNotesOption: 'input'
    releaseNotesInput: 'CI/CD Staging'
    destinationType: 'groups'
    distributionGroupId: 'XXX-xxx'
```

CICD is the name of the Service Connection.

Answer (score 1):

What about the service connection to App Center on your side?

I mean the CICD. Maybe you need to verify this to make it work.

Comment: The CICD is working for single project, looks like it had a incorrect API key.Another issue with the same is uploading multiple flavors builds to appcenter. Can we make the appslug and appFile part dynamic as in depending on the flavors uploading respective builds,right now it is giving error - cannot file the apk file